# C preprocessor in include header files

Tags: c, include, c-preprocessor

I have a structure defined in a header file called data.h.

I am including data.h in myfile.c.

In the structure, I have part of the variables blocked off with:

```
#ifndef TEST
 int x;
#endif
```

and in myfile.c I have:

```
#ifdef TEST
localx++;
#else
mystruct.x++; //<-compiler complains on this line when compiling
#endif
```

When I try to compile with `-DTEST` I get a compiler complaining that `mystruct` type does not containing a field called `x`. What is up with this?

I don't have a **C** compiler handy, so here is what I just typed up:

in data.h

```
typdef struct {

#ifndef TEST
int x;
#endif
int y;
} coords;
```

in myfile.c

```
#include "data.h" 
static coords coord1;
int localx;

int main( ) 
{ 
#ifdef TEST
  localx = 1;
#else
  coord1.x = 1;
#endif

  coord1.y = 2;
  printf("%i\n", coord1.x);
  printf("%i\n", coord1.y);
  printf("%i\n", localx);

  return 0; 
}
```

This compiles when I type `cc myfile.c` but not with `cc myfile.c -DTEST`
I am using the MIPSPro **C** compiler referenced [here](http://www.sgi.com/products/software/irix/tools/c.html).

Comment: Please show the complete declaration of the struct. Also, the part where it's included, and some code around the offending line

Comment: Could you make sure you're posting the real code?  Right now, it looks like there is an `x` if and only if it isn't used.  If there's a subtle error, we aren't going to catch it without the real code.

Comment: ok, tried to make an update post in code tags..but i think the # are throwing it off..but you can get the idea

Comment: @Derek: Exactly how are you invoking the compiler? - my quick test shows no problem with your example `data.h` and `myfile.c` examples (other than the typo for the keyword `typedef` in `data.h`) - with or without TEST being defined on the compiler command line.  You really should consider removing and reposting this question once you can provide exact cut-n-paste details from your problem so people here aren't chasing ghosts.

Comment: You have a typo in "typdef" but I guess it is just a copy-paste issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most recent edit (which may well be different by the time anyone reads this) will have a problem in the section that has a bunch of `printf()` statements.  The line:

```
 printf("%i\n", coord1.x);
```

is referencing the `x` member of the struct regardless of the setting of the `TEST` preprocessor macro.  It needs to be inside a conditional compilation section too in order to compile correctly (rather not compile at all) when the `x` member doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using ifndef for the field x, it is only there to use if TEST is not defined!!

#ifdef allows a section of a program to be compiled only if the macro that is specified as the parameter has been defined, no matter which its value is. For example:

```
#ifdef TABLE_SIZE

int table[TABLE_SIZE];

#endif
```

In this case, the line of code int table[TABLE_SIZE]; is only compiled if TABLE_SIZE was previously defined with #define, independently of its value. If it was not defined, that line will not be included in the program compilation.

#ifndef serves for the exact opposite: the code between #ifndef and #endif directives is only compiled if the specified identifier has not been previously defined. For example:

```
#ifndef TABLE_SIZE
#define TABLE_SIZE 100
#endif
int table[TABLE_SIZE];
```

In this case, if when arriving at this piece of code, the TABLE_SIZE macro has not been defined yet, it would be defined to a value of 100. If it already existed it would keep its previous value since the #define directive would not be executed.

From: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/

Comment: Registered User
 

Join Date: Nov 2009
Posts: 23  in data.h


Code:
typdef struct {
#ifndef TEST
int x;
#endif
int y;
} coords;
in myfile.c


Code:
#include "data.h"
static coords coord1;
int localx;

int main()
{
#ifdef TEST
localx = 1;
#else
coord1.x = 1;
#endif

coord1.y = 2;

printf("%i\n", coord1.x);
printf("%i\n", coord1.y);
printf("%i\n", localx);

return 0;
}

This compiles with "cc myfile.c" but does not compile with "cc myfile.c -DTEST" 

I am using the MIPSpro compiler on IRIX

Comment: He has the logic the right way 'round: if TEST is defined, don't add the variable to the struct and use the local variable; if TEST is not defined, add the variable to the struct and use it.

Comment: the #ifdef logic he shows is correct. He runs with -DTEST therefore x in struct should be defined, and so the code should compile. HE has a got subtle error somewhere, uncleo tried his posted code and it works fine

Comment: @pm100,@uncleo : You are right, my post was made before the edits of the question ... I might edit my post as well now

Comment: actually my comment is wrong, with #ifndef and -DTEST the struct x is not there , but the compile should not be trying to use it

Answer (score 0):

Except for the typo (typdef), your example compiles fine for me using gcc.

Edit:
The new example shouldn't compile. You need to wrap every reference to "x" in #ifdef directives.

Also, gcc accepts the -D flag before the file list, but I don't have access to MIPSpro. The docs say you have the command line out of order.